# scraping a website eith POST method

Tags: web-scraping

Hi im scraping a website [cleartrip.com](http://cleartrip.com)

I get the page info by this method :

```
$url = "http://www.cleartrip.com/m/flights/results?from=CCU&to=DEL&depart_date=22/06/2012&adults=1&childs=0&infants=0&dep_time=0&class=Economy&airline=&carrier=&x=57&y=16&flexi_search=no&tb=n";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "android Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 0.5; en-us)");
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Problem is i want those flights that have a stop ..............info is passed through post method but i don't know how i can get it?????

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to search the DOM for the element containing the info you want. Probably through a regular expression.

Comment: Well i didnt get wt you suggesting. I search out about selenium but how can i integrate it with php